# relationship between default table model and table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am new to java swing and I am working on build a GUI to display selected columns of data from a data frame.

When a column name is selected, I added the data and the column header by **DefaultTableModel** since **DefaultTableModel** is always applied to **JTable**.

When a column name is deselected, the column of data should be removed from **JTable** and there's a method called **"removeColumn"**, which could only remove the **"view"** -- the data still stays in the **DefaultTableModel**.

When the same column name is selected again, how can I display the column again without adding it again into the **DefaultTableModel** ?

Or, is it possible to build the full table(with all the columns) in **DefaultTableModel**, and only add part of them to the **JTable** for display (or not display) ?

I can't find a way to add values into a **DefaultTableColumnModel**..

Comment: *how can I display the column again* - the `TableColumnModel` of the `JTable`  allows you to add a `TableColumn` back to the view. *is it possible to build the full table(with all the columns) in DefaultTableModel, and only add part of them to the JTable for display (or not display) ?* Check out: [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/), which allows users to hide/show columns by clicking on the table header.

Comment: Could you please point out the function I can use to "add a TableColumn" back to view? I can't find it.. And I think I am not allowed to use a external library/

Comment: Sorry I am using DefaultTableModel, not the DefaultTableColumnModel(can I do the conversion somehow?)

Comment: The TableModel (using the default is a bad habit, just extend AbstractTableModel and make your own) is the lowest level representation of the data.  The Table is a view on that data. If you're wanting to hide columns and such, you need to set that in the table itself, not the model.  You might need to create your own TableColumnModel to handle your customizations. Look at third-party libraries like JIDE, you can get what you want and more.

Comment: The TableModel holds the data and is irrelevant in the question you asked. The `TableColumnModel` manages the view used by the `JTable`. Read the API for the `TableColumnModel`. You will find the `addColumn(…)` method that adds a `TableColumn` to the `TableColumnModel` of the `JTable`. If you look at the code in the link provided you will find methods like `hideColumn(…)` and `showColumn(…)`. The "hide" methods remove the `TableColumn` from the `TableColumnModel` and saves it so it can be restored. The "show" methods add the saved `TableColumn` back to the `TableColumnModel`.

Comment: The logic in the link provided attempts to add the TableColumn back in the same order it was originally displayed, which is why the logic may look a little complex. If you don't want to use the code provided then test out the code to understand how the code manipulated the TableColumnModel and implement your own logic.